# Could the DM allow an Artificer to create a homunculus servant via Replicate Magic Item?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

In [this forum discussion at D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/class-forums/artificer/91539-a-case-for-the-homunculus-infusion-on-a), it is proposed that a homunculus servant is a magic item. Therefore, if the DM ruled it, could an artificer use the replicate magic item class feature to make more than one homunculus servant?

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Please take some time to go through the [tour] and visit the [help] if you need more information. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 12):

“If the DM ruled it,” (and the players are still willing to play), *absolutely anything can happen*. That’s “Rule 0,” numbered 0 because it is absolutely fundamental to the game, before any of the regular rules.

So yes, the DM could rule that. Most DMs won’t, though, because Replicate Item only works with certain items listed in the book, not just any item you want. And a homunculus is not really a magic item in the same way. So the rules don’t allow this, and I don’t think many DMs are going to change the rules here.

But they could.

Comment: Related Background: [Rule Zero over the years](https://geek-related.com/2013/10/12/rule-zero-over-the-years/)

Answer (score 9):

### Not unless they overrule the feature

The homunculs servant is a magic item, because it is an infusion, and all infustions create magic items (*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, p. 12, Infuse Item):

> You've gained the ability to imbue mundane items with certain magical infusions, **turning those objects into magic items**.

The feature Replicate Magic Item says:

> Using this infusion, you replicate a particular magic item. You can learn this infusion multiple times; each time you do so, choose a magic item that you can make with it, **picking from the Replicable Items tables**. [...] If you have *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, you can choose from among the common magic items in that book when you pick a magic item you can replicate with this infusion.

The homunculus servant does not appear on any of the magic item tables listed for the feature, nor is is one of the common magic items listed in *Xanathar's Guide*. So by the rules, even though it is a magic item, you cannot create a second one with the  Replicate Magic Item infusion.

As [KRyan's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/209989/75095) says, a DM of course can always overrule the other written rules in their game. But apart from that, by the rules as written, this does not work.